# Java switch statement about number

Tags: java, switch-statement

I have a `switch` statement which works fine, but I feel like it's poorly formatted and redundant(many of the cases do the same thing). How can I improve this?

```
switch (number) {
    case 10: // do 1
        break;
    case 12: // do 2
        break;
    case 13: // do 1
        break;
    case 15: // do 3
        break;
    case 17: // do 2
        break;
    case 18: // do 2
        break;
}
```

Comment: it´s fine. no need to improve something here.

Comment: @SomeJavaGuy the answers below state otherwise

Comment: this sounds like a question for [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you can group the cases with the same output together. It is one way to improve this.

```
switch (number) {
    case 10:
    case 13:
        // do 1
        break;

    case 12:
    case 17:
    case 18:
        // do 2
        break;

    case 15: 
        // do 3
        break;
}
```

`break;` is used to terminate a case in the switch statement. So, the cases will have same output when there is no `break;` between them.

Answer (score 3):

You could improve it by removing a few break statement, like this

```
switch (number) {
case 10: 
case 13: // do 1
    break;
case 12: 
case 17:
case 18: // do 2
    break;
case 15: // do 3
    break;
}
```

Comment: This is very similar to Harmlezz's post. I would suggest adding new information somehow to avoid redundancy. But good quick Answer!

Comment: there is a missing colon after 17

Answer (score 2):

You may make it a bit more compact like this:

```
switch (number) {
case 10:
case 13:
    System.out.println("do 1 + " + number);
    break;
case 12:
case 17:
case 18:
    System.out.println("do 2 + " + number);
    break;
case 15:
    System.out.println("do 3 + " + number);
    break;
}
```

And the last `break;` is not required in your case but good practice anyways for defensive programming.

Answer (score 1):

You can add default case. When provided cases are not equal to number default statement is executed. Code:

```
int number = 0;
        switch (number) {
        case 10: // do 1
            break;
        case 12: // do 2
            break;
        case 13: // do 1
            break;
        case 15: // do 3
            break;
        case 17: // do 2
            break;
        case 18: // do 2
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println(number);
        }
```